# SVG not showing up

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a close button, that i want to display on the top right corner of my page.

The code of the svg is as follows

```css
.icon {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    /* changes to the fill do nothing */
    fill: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<svg class="icon">
<use xlink:href="#close" />
</svg>

<!-- some more code -->

<!-- SVG Icon Library -->
<svg style="display: none;">
<symbol id=close viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M19 6.41 17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z"></path>
</symbol>
</svg>
```

The icon is not showing up on the page

The following example is with an other icon. This one works...

```css
.icon {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    /* changes to the fill do nothing */
    fill: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<svg class="icon">
<use xlink:href="#info-outline" />
</svg>

<!-- some more code -->

<!-- SVG Icon Library -->
<svg style="display: none;">
<symbol id=info-outline viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M11 17h2v-6h-2v6zm1-15C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8zM11 9h2V7h-2v2z"></path>
</symbol>
</svg>
```

These examples are more or less the same and I'm clueless as to why that doesn't display the svg.

I tried changing the size of the svg, but the Dev-Tools show that the icon has a normal size.
Changes to the fill attribute also do nothing.
Other Svg's are working as expected and so should the close icon

Comment: As you can see your icons both work as snippets. You need to provide a testcase that demonstrates your issue because unfortunately this one does not.

Comment: Note that when used _in_ HTML5 source code, SVG does not use namespaces. There is no `xlink:href`, [only plain href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/href). That said, you snippet renders just fine, so there's nothing to fix here?

Answer (score 2):

If the icons are standard, well-known, not original, not designer, then you can use a ***Google character font***.
The choice and connection of icons from Google can be viewed  [here](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons)

> Material Icons are available in five styles and a range of
> downloadable sizes and densities. The icons are based on the core
> Material Design principles and metrics.

The desired icons are selected and added to the HTML by name: for example, click on the icon name `info` and copy the code.
Below is an example of using `close` and `info` icons. Added color change when hovering over icons.

```css
.material-symbols-outlined {
  margin: 10px;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.material-symbols-outlined:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
<span class="material-symbols-outlined"> close</span> 
 <span class="material-symbols-outlined">info</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help, but the way I handle svg's is by making an image instead putting the actual svg code in the html. It simplifies having to deal with the `viewBox` property. Instead, I import the svg into my project, then use it in either my css or html depending what type of svg it is. Then in the css I will set the desired width and height and I am done. An example is below.

```css
body {

  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}

#MySQL {

  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" theme="">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
   
   <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/qCH.svg" alt="MySQL" id="MySQL">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

- ID attributes are **not enclosed by quotes** (obviously, most Firefox and Chromium are quite forgiving)
- [`currentColor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/color) needs to be specified either on `<symbol>` or `<path>` level – otherwise, fill colors will fall back to black.
- **Double check your IDs for duplicates**

```css
.icon {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    fill: currentColor;
}


p{
  color:red
}

.green{
  color:green
}
```

```html
<p><svg class="icon">
    <use href="#close" />
  </svg>
</p>
<p class="green">
  <svg class="icon">
    <use href="#info-outline" />
  </svg>
</p>


<!-- SVG Icon Library -->
<svg style="width:0; height:0;">
  <symbol id="close" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor">
    <path d="M19 6.41 17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z" />
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="info-outline" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor">
    <path d="M11 17h2v-6h-2v6zm1-15C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8zM11 9h2V7h-2v2z" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

### It is 2023

Internet Explorer is dead.

All modern browsers support native JavaScript Web Components
(and have so for the past ***5 years***! since Edge switched to Chromium)

No need for oldskool `<symbol>` mumbo jumbo

We can write *semantic* HTML to display SVG icons

```html
   <svg-icon></svg-icon>
   <svg-icon is="info"></svg-icon>
   <svg-icon is="close"></svg-icon>
```

to output:

[image]

All code required:

**Note!** It totally does not matter **when** you define a Custom Element, all already created (but *undefined*) tags will automagically upgrade.

```js
customElements.define("svg-icon", class extends HTMLElement{
  connectedCallback(){
    let size = "148px";
    Object.assign( this.style , {
      width         : size,
      height        : size,
      display       : "inline-block",
      cursor        : "pointer"
    });
    let dpath = {
      "close" : "M19 6.41 17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z",
      "info"  : "M11 17h2v-6h-2v6zm1-15C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8zM11 9h2V7h-2v2z"
    }[ this.getAttribute("is") || "info" ];
    this.innerHTML = `<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="${dpath}"/></svg>`;
  }
})
```

```css
svg-icon[is="close"] {
    fill: red;
}
svg-icon:hover {
    fill: green;
}
```

```html
<svg-icon></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is="info"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is="close"></svg-icon>
```